# How can I save a record before running a custom process?

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom process for the Sales Order screen that populates the Details grid with values obtained from another table/DAC.   The problem is that I need to save the record, which will create an Order Nbr, before the process runs.  I've tried to add this code to the process method as follows:

```
    protected virtual IEnumerable licensePlateLoad(PXAdapter adapter)
    {

        //Issue a save first...
        Base.Actions.PressSave();

        //Declare the grid's DAC...
        SOLine soline;

        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate ()
        {
             //...process code here...
        });
```

I've also tried to use Base.Persist() in the same spot as Base.Actions.PressSave(), but neither of these actions create the new record before running the process.  Any ideas?

Comment: If the record (header) has all his required fields populated that code should work. In Acumatica is a common practice to Save before running a Action that will lead on a Async process. Not sure why is not working, you can also try with `Save.Press()` but the code you are proposing should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the adapter from the action into the .PressSave() method

So Base.Actions.PressSave(adapter);

Comment: That did it, thanks Kyle.  The only problem I have now is how to get the saved record to be the current one.  As it stands, it still shows a <NEW> record when the process is finished, but if you search the selector you can see and bring up the newly created one.

(Just an FYI - I used Base.Save.Press(adapter) because Base.Actions.PressSave() didn't accept any arguments).

Comment: Sounds good, make another stack ticket for that and I will answer it, I have run into that before as well. FYI, Base.Actions.PressSave() and Base.Save.Press() are functionally identical, one just doesn't accept an adapter as you saw.